# MVC VB.NET webpage with Javascript Dynamic created table save to sql

Tags: javascript, vb.net, model-view-controller

first post here, I've being developing sites for some time using MVC and VB.NET but currently I have a request to create or add dynamically lines to a table and store or save this data into a table. I am working with the following to create this. please notice that the site has to parts, the first part contains the static values that are stored in another table but related to the table that is stored in another table. Any help will be appreciated.

The below code controls the "post" button and I want to go through all columns and rows, save them as an array then post it a table in SQL and I will take it from there, but the code below does nothing. Take in consideration that I need the fields "open" for edit in all rows until the "post" button is hit.

``
("#buttonPost").on("click", function () {

```
            var tbl = document.getElementById('tblEventPrices');
            var rCount = tbl.rows.length;
            //try {
            //    alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 1].cells[0].children[0].value);
            //    alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 2].cells[0].children[0].value);
            //    alert(rCount);
            //    //alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 1].cells[1].children[0].value);

            //} catch (e) {
            //    alert(e);
            //}
            //var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
            //for (var i = 0, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
            //    //iterate through rows
            //    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
            //    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            //        //iterate through columns
            //        //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
            //        alert(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value);
            //    }
            //}
            //for (var i = 0 ; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

            //    var row = "";

            //    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {

            //        row += tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
            //        row += " | ";
            //    }

            //    alert(row);

            //};

            //var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
            for (var i = 0, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
                //iterate through rows
                //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    //iterate through columns
                    //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                    alert(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value)
                }
            }
            alert(tbl.rows[1].cells[0].children[0].value);
            alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 1].cells[0].children[0].value);
            //});
        });
```

`

Full Code Below

```
@ModelType EventsModel

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Crear Evento"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear Evento"
End Code

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<hr />
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <section id="UpdateEventForm">
                    @Using Html.BeginForm("Create", "Events", New With {.ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data", .class = "form-horizontal", .role = "form"})
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @<text>
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                <div Class="form-group">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Crear Marca", "BrandCreate", "Events")
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Brand_Name, New With {.class = "col-md-4 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Brand_ID, New SelectList(Model.EventsDataList_Brand, "Brand_ID", "Brand_Name"), "Marca...", New With {.Class = "form-control"})
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Brand_ID, "", New With {.Class = "text-danger"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div Class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.EventCategoryName, New With {.class = "col-md-4 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Category_ID, New SelectList(Model.EventsDataList_Category, "Category_ID", "EventCategoryName"), "Categoría...", New With {.Class = "form-control"})
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Category_ID, "", New With {.Class = "text-danger"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Event_Name, New With {.class = "col-md-6 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Event_Name, New With {.placeholder = "Nombre del Evento", .class = "form-control", .style = "padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.7px solid;border-Left: 0.7px solid; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;"})
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Event_Name, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Event_Description, New With {.class = "col-md-6 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.Event_Description, New With {.placeholder = "Detalles del Evento", .class = "form-control input-lg textarea-editor PETextEditor", .TextMode = "MultiLine", .rows = "5", .style = "padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.7px solid;border-Left: 0.7px solid; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;"})
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Event_Description, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @*<div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Event_Short_Description, New With {.class = "col-md-8 control-label"})
                                        <div Class="col-md-offset-6 ">
                                            @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.Event_Short_Description, New With {.placeholder = "Descripción del Evento", .rows = "5", .class = "form-control", .style = "padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.7px solid;border-Left: 0.7px solid; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;width:800;"})
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Event_Short_Description, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                                        </div>
                                    </div>*@
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Event_Date_Start, New With {.class = "col-md-6 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Event_Date_Start, New With {.class = "form-control", .style = "padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.7px solid;border-Left: 0.7px solid; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;"})
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Event_Description, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Event_Date_End, New With {.class = "col-md-6 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Event_Date_End, New With {.class = "form-control", .style = "padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.7px solid;border-Left: 0.7px solid; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Is_Full_Day, New With {.class = "col-md-6 control-label"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Is_Full_Day, New With {.class = "form-control", .style = "padding: 10px; border-bottom: 0.7px solid;border-Left: 0.7px solid; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Event_Poster_File, New With {.class = "control-label col-md-8"})
                                    <div Class="col-md-offset-4 ">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Event_Poster_File, New With {.type = "file", .aria_describedby = "fileHelp", .Class = "form-control-file"})
                                        <small id="fileHelp" Class="form-text text-muted">Poster o imagen del evento</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-center">
                                                <input type="button" id="StartButton" value="Agregar Tipo de Boleto" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="GeneralPrice()" />
                                                    <input id="AddRowButtom" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Add Row"/>
                                                @*<input type="button" id="StartButton" value="Boleto de Cortesía" c@*lass="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="GiftPrice()" />
                                                    <input type="button" id="StartButton" value="Donación" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="PromoPrice()" />*@
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <table id="tblEventPrices" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    @*<th>
                                                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Price_Name)
                                                        </th>*@
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Price_Description)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Price)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Price_Qty)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Tax_1)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Tax_2)
                                                    </th>
                                                    @*<th><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Agregar" /></th>*@
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            @code dim i As Int32 = 1 end code
                                            @If (Model.EventsDetails IsNot Nothing) Then
                                                @For Each item In Model.EventsDetails.ToList()
                                                    @<tr>
                                                        @*<td>
                                                                @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.EventsDetails(i).Price_Name, New With {.id = "txtPriceName_" + i})
                                                            </td>*@
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.EventsDetails(i).Event_Price_Description, New With {.id = "txtPriceDescription_" + i})
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.EventsDetails(i).Event_Price, New With {.id = "txtPrice_" + i})
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.EventsDetails(i).Event_Price_Qty, New With {.id = "txtPriceQty_" + i})
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.EventsDetails(i).Event_Tax_1, New With {.id = "txtTax1_" + i})
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.EventsDetails(i).Event_Tax_2, New With {.id = "txtTax2_" + i})
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><input type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="Remove(this)" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                        @code i = i + 1 end code
                                                            Next
                                                               End If
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                        <input type="submit" id="btnSavePublish" value="Publicar" formaction="CreateSubmitPublish" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="SubmitPublish" />
                                        <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Guardar" formaction="EventCreate" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="CreateEvent" />
                                        @*<input type="submit" id="btnSaveSubmitPreview" value="Guardar y Vista Previa" formaction="@Url.Action("CreateSubmitPreview")" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="SubmitPreview" />*@
                                        <input type="button" id="btnSaveSubmitPreview" value="Guardar y Vista Previa" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="SubmitPreview" />
                                        <input id="buttonPost" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Postar" />
                                        @*<input type="submit" value="Crear" formaction="PricesSubmitDetails" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="submitDetails" />*@
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </text>
                                                            End Using
                </section>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    @Section Scripts
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinymce.init({ menubar: false, mode: 'specific_textareas', width: 800, editor_selector: 'PETextEditor', theme: 'modern' });
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AddRowButtom").on("click", function () {
                var table = document.getElementById('tblEventPrices');

                var nextIndex = table.childNodes.length;
                var htmlLbl = '<tr><td><input type="text" id="txtPriceDescription"/></td><td><input type="number" id="txtPrice" min="1" /></td><td><input type="number" id="txtPriceQty" min="1" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="txtTax1" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="txtTax2" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="Remove(this)" /></td></tr>';

                table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = htmlLbl
            });

            $("#buttonPost").on("click", function () {

                var tbl = document.getElementById('tblEventPrices');
                var rCount = tbl.rows.length;
                //try {
                //    alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 1].cells[0].children[0].value);
                //    alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 2].cells[0].children[0].value);
                //    alert(rCount);
                //    //alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 1].cells[1].children[0].value);

                //} catch (e) {
                //    alert(e);
                //}
                //var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
                //for (var i = 0, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
                //    //iterate through rows
                //    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
                //    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                //        //iterate through columns
                //        //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                //        alert(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value);
                //    }
                //}
                //for (var i = 0 ; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

                //    var row = "";

                //    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {

                //        row += tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value;
                //        row += " | ";
                //    }

                //    alert(row);

                //};

                //var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
                for (var i = 0, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
                    //iterate through rows
                    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
                    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                        //iterate through columns
                        //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                        alert(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value)
                    }
                }
                alert(tbl.rows[1].cells[0].children[0].value);
                alert(tbl.rows[rCount - 1].cells[0].children[0].value);
                //});
            });
        });

        function Remove(button) {
            //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
            var row = $(button).closest("TR");
            var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
            //if (confirm("Estás seguro de borrar: " + name)) {
            if (confirm("Estás seguro de borrar")) {
                //Get the reference of the Table.
                var table = $("#tblEventPrices")[0];

                //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
                table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
            }
        };
    </script>
    End Section

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  In order for others to help you, please specify exactly what your expected result is and what you are getting instead.

Comment: Hello levininja, I have given more details, thanks for your patience and comment, hope the details I have added make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this issue below the code, the issue is that each row had the same "id", although this was answer in another question, the difference is that this page that I have built each line is editable, so the way to access the table data is a little different, this cost me 20 bucks but hope to help somebody else.

Below how the table gets loaded

```
 <table id="tblEventPrices" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    @*<th>
                                                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Price_Name)
                                                        </th>*@
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Price_Description)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Price)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Price_Qty)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Tax_1)
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Event_Tax_2)
                                                    </th>
                                                    @*<th><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Agregar" /></th>*@
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="tblEventPricesbody"></tbody>
                                        </table>
```

And this is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AddRowButtom").on("click", function () {
                var table = document.getElementById('tblEventPrices');

                var tbodyRowCount = table.tBodies[0].rows.length;
                var rowId = tbodyRowCount + 1;
                var last_id = $('#tblEventPricesbody tr:last').attr('id');
                if (rowId == last_id) {
                    rowId = rowId + 1;
                }
                //alert(rowId);
                var htmlLbl = '<tr id="' + rowId + '"><td><input type="text" id="txtPriceDescription_' + rowId + '"/></td><td><input type="number" id="txtPrice_' + rowId + '" min="1" /></td><td><input type="number" id="txtPriceQty_' + rowId + '" min="1" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="txtTax1_' + rowId + '" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="txtTax2_' + rowId + '" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Borrar" onclick="Remove(' + rowId + ')" /></td></tr>';

                $("#tblEventPricesbody").append(htmlLbl);
            });

            $("#buttonPost").on("click", function () {
                var EvDesc = '';
                var EvPrice = '';
                var EvQTY = '';
                var EvTax1 = '';
                var EvTax2 = '';
                var trid = '';
                var userName = '@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name';
                var EventPrices = new Array();
                var BrandId = $("#BrandId").val();
                var CategoryID = $("#CategoryId").val();
                var EventName = $("#EventName").val();
                var EventDescription = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
                var EventFacebook = $("#EventFacebook").val();
                var EventInstagram = $("#EventInstagram").val();
                var EventTwitter = $("#EventTwitter").val();
                var EventPersonalizedUrl = $("#EventPersonalizedUrl").val();
                var EventDateStart = $("#Event_Date_Start").val();
                var EventDateEnd = $("#Event_Date_End").val();
                var IsFullDay = $("#Is_Full_Day").is(":checked");
                var EventPosterFile = $("#EventPosterFile").val();
                var priceData = {};
                priceData.Brand_Id = BrandId;
                priceData.Category_ID = CategoryID;
                priceData.Event_Name = EventName;
                priceData.Event_Description = EventDescription;
                priceData.Event_Facebook = EventFacebook;
                priceData.Event_Instagram = EventInstagram;
                priceData.Event_Twitter = EventTwitter;
                priceData.Event_Personalized_Url = EventPersonalizedUrl;
                priceData.Event_Date_Start = EventDateStart;
                priceData.Event_Date_End = EventDateEnd;
                priceData.Is_Full_Day = IsFullDay;
                priceData.Event_Poster_File = EventPosterFile;
                EventPrices.push(priceData);
                $("#tblEventPricesbody tr").each(function () {
                    trid = this.id;
                    var price = {};
                    price.EvDesc = $("#txtPriceDescription_" + trid).val();
                    price.EvPrice = $("#txtPrice_" + trid).val();
                    price.EvQTY = $("#txtPriceQty_" + trid).val();
                    price.EvTax1 = $("#txtTax1_" + trid).is(":checked");
                    price.EvTax2 = $("#txtTax2_" + trid).is(":checked");
                    price.userName = userName
                    EventPrices.push(price);
                     //alert(EvDesc + "|" + EvPrice + "|" + EvQTY + "|" + EvTax1 + "|" + EvTax2 + "|" + trid);
                });
                alert(JSON.stringify(EventPrices))

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "@Url.Action("PricesTemp")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(EventPrices),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
                });
            });
```